# FullCalendar date & time handling

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I am using the [FullCalendar script](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/) and am having trouble formatting the date/time of EVENTS on the calendar.

I need all the events date/time data to look like:

> **2011-09-28 08:15:00**

All the dates are like this in my JSON source, which display on the calendar correctly. However, if the event is moved or a new event is added (dropped by eternal dragging), the time format looks like:

> **Fri Sep 30 2011 14:30:00 GMT-0400 (EDT)**

It doesn't DISPLAY in that format, but it appears this way when I try to insert the event.start or event.end into my database, or when I do this:

```
eventClick: function(event) {

alert("Event ID: " + event.id + " Start Date: " + event.start + " End Date: " + event.end);
}
```

I am using this only to see how the date & time are saved within the calendar. I need to update my database with new events, but in the format first shown above, but I am having trouble doing this.

How do I use the `formatDate` function? I see it listed, and the reason I'm asking is because I don't know what to do with it.

I did:

```
$.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.start, 'MM-dd-yyyy');
```

but that doesn't do anything...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what I did, is, first put it in a var, but only seemed to work in IE - FF still produced the IETF format (ex: "Wed, 18 Oct 2009 13:00:00 EST"):

```
var formDate = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.start, 'MM-dd-yyyy');
alert(" Start Date: " + formDate);
```

Comment: formatDate is no longer supported. For > v1 use moment() as discussed below

Answer (score 14):

Just use the following code before you render your events:

```
start=moment(start).format('YYYY/MM/DD hh:mm');
```

```
end=moment(end).format('YYYY/MM/DD hh:mm');
```

Make sure you are using moment.js.

Answer (score 1):

I have found your answer in a similar question, in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18551331/fullcalendar-date-format)

Answered by H.D:

```
dateStr = "Tue Aug 13 2013 18:00:00 GMT-0400 (EDT)"
(new Date(dateStr)).toISOString().slice(0, 10)
```

It will display: '2013-08-13'

```
(new Date(dateStr)).toISOString()
```

It will display: '2013-08-13T18:00:00.000Z'

Comment: Thank you very much! I don't know why your answer is not at the top.

Answer (score 1):

I have used below code while rendering the event on calendar.

Hope this code help you.

```
  eventRender: function(event, element) {
          eventsdate = moment(event.start).format('hh:mm a');
          eventedate = moment(event.end).format('hh:mm a');

          element.find('.fc-time').html(eventsdate + " - " + eventedate + "<br>");
}
```

Make sure you are using moment.js

Answer (score 0):

Check out [formatDate](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/utilities/formatDate/) and [parseDate](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/utilities/parseDate/) and it'll probably solve your problems.

Comment: I've been trough it all. If I hadn't, I wouldn't have posted the question. I know it's explained somewhere, but I'm not very fluent in jquery/javascript. If someone could post how to do this here I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

**Q : How do I use the formatDate function? I see it listed, the reason I'm asking is because I don't know what to do with it. I did:
$.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.start, 'MM-dd-yyyy');
That doesn't do anything...**

Answer :

You can use look likes :

```
eventClick: function(event) {

alert("Event ID: " + event.id + " Start Date: " +  $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.start, 'MM-dd-yyyy') + " End Date: " + event.end);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to pass date object from java to full calendar and using Java 7 or lesser, below function will work for you.

```
Date date= new Date("passyourdatestring");
date.toLocaleString();
```

And following will be the event object.

```
{
  id: '_jobName' ,
  url: 'url ',
  title: 'title',
  allDay: 'false',
  description: 'displayname',
  start': 'schedDateTime',
  end: date.toLocaleString()
}
```