# FullCalendar date format

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

Want to find the way to change the default date format in FullCalendar.

**Actually, it is:**
Tue Aug 13 2013 18:00:00 GMT-0400 (EDT)

**I want:**
2013-08-13

Thanks.

Comment: Hi, please remember to always Google first. A query for `FullCalendar date format` should give you all you need.

Comment: Hi. Do you really think I did not make it before joining SO?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For information specific to the FullCalendar, you probably need to see [this](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/utilities/formatDate/), which gives you some formating rules. There's some more information [here](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/text/titleFormat/) that might be useful.

---

Yet, you can do so with JavaScript directly if you need this date format in an interface between the FullCalendar and other package or your own code:

If you want "today", you can (be careful since that'll be client-side):

```
> (new Date()).toISOString().slice(0, 10)
'2013-08-31'
```

And from the string you said, you can:

```
> dateStr = "Tue Aug 13 2013 18:00:00 GMT-0400 (EDT)"
> (new Date(dateStr)).toISOString().slice(0, 10)
'2013-08-13'
```

Both would give you the ISO date in UTC. For locale date, you should "move" your time object to UTC before using `.toISOString`. Let:

```
> dateStr = "Mon Aug 12 2013 22:00:00 GMT-0400 (EDT)"
> dateObj = new Date(dateStr) /* Or empty, for today */
> dateIntNTZ = dateObj.getTime() - dateObj.getTimezoneOffset() * 60 * 1000
> dateObjNTZ = new Date(dateIntNTZ)
> dateObjNTZ.toISOString().slice(0, 10)
'2013-08-12'
```

Locale can still be different from GMT-0400 given in your example (here it's GMT-0300, at the end it gives me 1 hour after the one in this example).

---

I'll replicate here the information from the first FullCalendar link I said:

## formatDate

Formats a Date object into a string.

```
$.fullCalendar.formatDate( date, formatString [, options ] ) -> String
```

Prior to version 1.3, formatDate accepted a very different format. See [here](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/utilities/formatDate_pre_13/).

`formatString` is a combination of any of the following commands:

- **s** - seconds
- **ss** - seconds, 2 digits
- **m** - minutes
- **mm** - minutes, 2 digits
- **h** - hours, 12-hour format
- **hh** - hours, 12-hour format, 2 digits
- **H** - hours, 24-hour format
- **HH** - hours, 24-hour format, 2 digits
- **d** - date number
- **dd** - date number, 2 digits
- **ddd** - date name, short
- **dddd** - date name, full
- **M** - month number
- **MM** - month number, 2 digits
- **MMM** - month name, short
- **MMMM** - month name, full
- **yy** - year, 2 digits
- **yyyy** - year, 4 digits
- **t** - 'a' or 'p'
- **tt** - 'am' or 'pm'
- **T** - 'A' or 'P'
- **TT** - 'AM' or 'PM'
- **u** - ISO8601 format
- **S** - 'st', 'nd', 'rd', 'th' for the date
- **W** - the [ISO8601 week number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Week_dates)

Special Characters:

`'...'`
literal text

`''`
single quote (represented by two single quotes)

`(...)`
only displays format if one of the enclosed variables is non-zero

The `options` parameter can be used to override default locale options, such as [monthNames](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/text/monthNames/), [monthNamesShort](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/text/monthNamesShort/), [dayNames](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/text/dayNames/), and [dayNamesShort](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/text/dayNamesShort/).

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```
      select: function (start, end, allDay) {             
        var startFix= moment($.fullCalendar.formatDate(start, 'YYYY-MM-DD'));               
        newCalendar(startFix);           
    }
```