# toISOString() return wrong date

Tags: javascript, date

Why did this piece of code return tomorrow's date ?

It must return 2013-08-31 and not 2013-09-01 as we are August 31st.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_toisostring

```js
function myFunction() {
  var d = new Date();
  var x = document.getElementById("demo");
  x.innerHTML = d.toISOString();
}
```

```html
<p id="demo">Click the button to display the date and time as a string, using the ISO
  standard.</p>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString

Comment: How can I take MY jour and not UTC one ?

Comment: Just see this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16084313/issue-with-toisostring-function

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18551331/fullcalendar-date-format

Answer (score 6):

It's in UTC.

If you want to get your local timezone you have to format the date yourself (using `getYear()` `getMonth()` etc.) or use some library like [date.js](http://www.datejs.com/) that will format the date for you.

With date.js it's pretty simple:

```
(new Date()).format('yyyy-MM-dd')
```

**edit**

As @MattJohnson noted date.js has been abandoned, but you can use alternatives like [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/).

Comment: @Francois by using getYear()  etc, but the solution you found in the other question is better. Using date.js is better still.

Comment: Use [moment.js](http://momentjs.com), not date.js.  [It's been abandoned](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/datejs/info).

Comment: Using moment instead of d.toISOString() just write moment(d).toISOString().

Comment: [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/) also recommends to use [alternatives](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/recommendations/). As stated on their website: *"We now generally consider Moment to be a legacy project in maintenance mode. It is not dead, but it is indeed done."*

Answer (score 5):

use:

```
new Date().toLocaleDateString('pt-br').split( '/' ).reverse( ).join( '-' );
```

or

```
(function() {

    function pad(number) {
      if (number < 10) {
        return '0' + number;
      }
      return number;
    }

    Date.prototype.toISO1String = function() {
      return this.getFullYear() +
        '-' + pad(this.getMonth() + 1) +
        '-' + pad(this.getDate()) +
        'T' + pad(this.getHours()) +
        ':' + pad(this.getMinutes()) +
        ':' + pad(this.getSeconds()) +
        '.' + (this.getMilliseconds() / 1000).toFixed(3).slice(2, 5) +
        'Z';
    };

  })();
```

See: [mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString) toISOString doc

I just modified it

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use [Luxon](https://www.npmjs.com/package/luxon).

```
DateTime.fromJSDate(new Date(yourDateVariable)).toFormat('yyyy-MM-dd')
```