# Why converting my date to toISOString adds extra day to my date in TypeScript

Tags: angular, typescript

I have date in Typescript when I convert it to (toISOString) it adds an extra day, it makes my code confusing.

see the code:

```
   this.mycurrentDate= new Date();
   console.log(this.mycurrentDate);
   //**result: Sun Jun 28 2020 22:42:50 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)**
   this.mycurrentDate= this.mycurrentDate.toISOString();
   console.log(this.mycurrentDate);
   //**result: 2020-06-29T02:42:50.991Z**
```

Comment: toISOString will return the timezone which is always zero UTC offset

Comment: Does this answer your question? [toISOString() return wrong date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18554360/toisostring-return-wrong-date)

Comment: No how can I fix it that example is in Javascript and moment.js do you know how to fix it in TypeScript, how can I resolve this issue

Comment: You haven't described your issue. The code is behaving as per specification. Your question doesn't mention what you're trying to achieve...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because ISO format is always in UTC instead of your local timezone and is a few hours ahead. It's just like if you had a friend living in Britain; the time on their clocks is going to be ahead of your clocks in EST. Timezones in general are a nightmare, but what you have is just standardizing your timezone to match the ISO standard -- it isn't skipping ahead a day, and the actual time is the same.